# Is there a “universal” Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

**Question.** Is there a Hausdorff space $ X $ such that every Hausdorff space $ Y $ can be embedded into $ X^\Lambda $ (given the product topology) for some sets $ \Lambda $?

Concerning Tychonoff spaces, $ X = [0, 1] $ satisfies the condition; i.e., every Tychonoff space can be embedded into some powers of $ [0, 1] $. I wonder if there is a counterpart for Hausdorff spaces.

I tried to disprove the existence by proving that for every Hausdorff space $ X $ there exists a non-trivial Hausdorff space $ Y $ such that there are only a few continuous maps from $ Y $ into $ X $, but I got stuck.

Comment: Does every space $Y$ have a different power $\Lambda(Y)$?

Comment: For any space $X$ there is a universal hausdorff space $X_\text{Haus}$ in the sense that every continuous map $X\rightarrow Y$ into a hausdorff space $Y$ factors uniquely via $X_\text{Haus}$. But this doesn’t seem to be the kind of universal object you are asking for...

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, $ Λ $ can depend on $ Y $.

Comment: Every subspace of a completely regular space is also completely regular, so non-completely regular spaces cannot be embedded into a product of intervals.

Comment: I think the answer should be no based on the fact that there is no Hausdorff space $Y$ such that for every Hausdorff space $X$ the points of $X$ can be separated by maps into $Y$, so for any fixed Hausdorff $Y$ and $\lambda$ there is an Hausdorff space $X$ such that there no continuous injections $X\to Y^\lambda$, but I'm not seeing how to reach a clear contradiction

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti How can I prove your former statement that for each Hausdorff $Y$ there is a Hausdorff space $X$, whose points are not separated by maps into $Y$?

Comment: @HanulJeon I learned that fact from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465257/is-there-a-hausdorff-space-x-separating-points-of-any-hausdorff-space) a while ago, there is a proof in the answer

Comment: See also my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1950171/86856 which is answering a rather different question but implies a negative answer to your question (at most one of the two spaces $X$ and $X'$ can embed in a power of $Y$, since they have the same "universal" map to a power of $Y$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/471523/4280) the following fact is shown:

> Given any Hausdorff space $X$, there exists a Hausdorff $Y$ and distinct $a,b\in Y$ such that each continuous $f\colon Y\to X$ satisfies $f(a)=f(b)$.

So if such a universal space $X$ existed, find $Y$ as promised by this fact.

Being universal, there must be an embedding $e: Y \to X^I$ for some index set $I$.
But with $a,b$ from the fcat we see right away that for each $i \in I$, $\pi_i(e(a)) = \pi_i(e(b))$ (as $\pi_i \circ e$ is continuous from $Y$ to $X$) and thus $e(a)= e(b)$ and this contradicts the injectivity of $e$.

So there can be no universal Hausdorff space.

Comment: For $T_1$ (aka Fréchet) spaces no such space can exist as well, I sketch a construction from paper by Herrlich [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3186273/4280). $T_0$ spaces have Sierpi&nacute;ski space as a universal power space, and like the OP said $[0,1]$ works for completely regular $T_1$ spaces. The classes inbetween have not.

Comment: Ah of course, I should have seen this argument after remembering the fact, very neat