# $Y$ is $T_1$ iff there is regular space $X$ s.t. all continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is constant

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand [this](http://msleziak.com/texty/translat/) article. This article states that $Y$ is $T_1$ space iff there exists a regular space $X$ (having at least two points), such that every continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ is constant.

I do not understand the construction of space $X$. Please anyone help me to show what regular space $X$ that satisfies that condition if $Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $Y = \Bbb{R}$ what topology are you equipping $Y$ with? The standard topology is not just $T_1$

Comment: I consider the standard topology

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect some corrections pointed out to me by @BrianM.Scott (and a link to a related answer of his), and it also has more references now.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the paper you are linking to is translation of the paper Horst Herrlich: *Wann sind alle stetigen Abbildungen in $Y$ konstant?* I have made the translation based on the request of the poster of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72442/existence-of-non-constant-continuous-functions).

Answer (score 5):

Eric van Douwen’s paper ‘A regular space on which every continuous real-valued function is constant’, Nieuw Arch. Wisk. **$30$** $(1972)$, $143$-$145$, actually gives a ‘machine’ for starting with a $T_3$ space having two points that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function and producing from it a $T_3$ space on which all continuous real-valued functions are constant. I no longer have a copy of the paper or easy access to it, so I’m working from memory, but the construction below is either the same as or very similar to Eric’s.

Let $Z$ be any $T_3$ space with points $p$ and $q$ that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function. Let $Y=Z\setminus\{p,q\}$, and let $\kappa=|Y|$. Give $\kappa$ the discrete topology, and let $X=\kappa\times Z$ with the resulting product topology. For notational convenience let $X_\xi=\{\xi\}\times Z$, $p_\xi=\langle\xi,p\rangle$, and $q_\xi=\langle\xi,q\rangle$ for $\xi<\kappa$. Clearly $\kappa$ is infinite, so there is a bijection $\varphi:\kappa\to\kappa\times Y\subseteq X$. We may (and do) further assume that if $\varphi(\xi)=\langle\eta,y\rangle$, then $\eta\ne\xi$.

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ as follows.

- Of course $x\sim x$ for all $x\in X$.
- We identify all copies of $p$ to a single point: $p_\xi\sim p_\eta$ for all $\xi,\eta<\kappa$.
- For all $\xi<\kappa$, $q_\xi\sim\varphi(\xi)$; this identifies each point of $\kappa\times Y$ with a unique $q_\xi$.

Let $X'=X/\!\sim$; we hope to show that $X'$ is $T_3$, and that every real-valued continuous function on $X'$ is constant.

Think of $Z$ as a string with endpoints $p$ and $q$. The idea of $\sim$ is to glue all of the copies of $p$ together into one point $p^*$, and then to run a separate string from $p^*$ to each other point, gluing the $q$ end of that string to the point. (I’ve always thought of this construction as Eric’s Spaghetti Machine.) This ought to ensure that if $x$ and $y$ are any points of $X'$, and $f:X'\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, the string from $p^*$ to $x$ ensures that $f(x)=f(p^*)$, while the string from $p^*$ to $y$ ensures that $f(y)=f(p^*)$, so that $f(x)=f(y)$.

And in fact it does. Let $\pi:X\to X'$ be the canonical quotient map, and let $p^*=\pi(p_0)$ (which is of course the same as $\pi(p_\xi)$ for each $\xi<\kappa$). If $f:X'\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, then $f\circ\pi:X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous. Let $g=f\circ\pi$; then $g(p_\xi)=g(q_\xi)$ for all $\xi<\kappa$, since $g\upharpoonright X_\xi$ is a continuous real-valued function on $X_\xi$, which is homeomorphic to $Z$. Let $x'\in X'\setminus \{p^*\}$ be arbitrary. Then $x'=\pi\big(\langle\eta,y\rangle\big)$ for some $\langle\eta,y\rangle\in\kappa\times Y$, and there is a $\xi\in\kappa\setminus\{\eta\}$ such that $\varphi(\xi)=\langle\eta,y\rangle$. Then $\pi(q_\xi)=\pi\big(\varphi(\xi)\big)=\pi\big(\langle\eta,y\rangle\big)$, so $f(x')=g\big(\langle\eta,y\rangle\big)=g(q_\xi)=g(p_\xi)=f(p^*)$, and $f$ is indeed constant on $X'$.

It’s actually harder to show that $X'$ is $T_3$.

Let $x'\in X'\setminus\{p^*\}$; there is some $\langle\eta,y\rangle\in\kappa\times Y$ such that $x'=\pi\big(\langle\eta,y\rangle\big)$. Let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x'$; the $\sim$-equivalence classes are closed in $X$, so $X'$ is $T_1$, and without loss of generality we may assume that $\pi(q_\eta)\notin U$. Let $V_0=X_\eta\cap\pi^{-1}[U]$; $V_0$ is an open nbhd of $y$ in $X$. Let

$$K_0=\{\xi<\kappa:\varphi(\xi)\in V_0\}=\{\xi<\kappa:\pi(q_\xi)\in\pi[V_0]\}\;,$$

and let $$V_1=\bigcup_{\xi\in K_0}\big(X_\xi\cap\pi^{-1}[U]\big)\;.$$

In general, given $V_n$ for some $n\in\omega$, let

$$K_n=\{\xi<\kappa:\varphi(\xi)\in V_n\}=\{\xi<\kappa:\pi(q_\xi)\in\pi[V_n]\}\;,$$

and let $$V_{n+1}=\bigcup_{\xi\in K_n}\big(X_\xi\cap\pi^{-1}[U]\big)\;.$$

Finally, let $V=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}V_n$; then $V=\pi^{-1}[U]$.

There is an open nbhd $W_0$ of $\langle\eta,y\rangle$ in $X$ such that $\operatorname{cl}_XW_0\subseteq V_0$. For each $\xi\in\bigcup_{n\in\omega}K_n$ there is an open nbhd $G_\xi$ of $q_\xi$ in $X$ such that $G_\xi\subseteq X_\xi$, and $\operatorname{cl}_XG_\xi\subseteq\pi^{-1}[U]$. Given $W_n$ for some $n\in\omega$, let $L_n=\{\xi<\kappa:\pi(q_\xi)\in\pi[W_n]\}$, and let

$$W_{n+1}=W_n\cup\bigcup_{\xi\in L_n}G_\xi\;.$$

Then $W=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}W_n$ is open in $X$, and $W=\pi^{-1}\big[\pi[W]\big]$, so $\pi[W]$ is an open nbhd of $x'$ in $X'$. Let $H_0=\operatorname{cl}_XW_0$. Given $H_n$ for some $n\in\omega$, let $M_n=\{\xi<\kappa:q_\xi\in\pi[H_n]\}$, and let

$$H_{n+1}=H_n\cup\bigcup_{\xi\in M_n}\operatorname{cl}_XG_\xi\;.$$

Then $H=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}H_n$ is closed in $X$, and $\pi^{-1}\big[\pi[H]\big]=H$, so $\pi[H]$ is closed in $X'$. Clearly $\pi[W]\subseteq\pi[H]\subseteq U$, so

$$x'\in\pi[W]\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_{X'}\pi[W]\subseteq\pi[H]\subseteq U\;.$$

I leave it to you to modify the argument slightly to show that $X'$ is $T_3$ at the point $p^*$ as well.

Comment: thank you for the proof. But can you so me what a continuous map define on space that is defined in A. Mysior's paper is not constant?

Comment: @flourence: Let $f(\langle x,1\rangle)=1$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$, and let $f$ send every other point of the space to $0$; then $f$ is continuous but not constant.

Comment: This is funny: searching for the title of van Douwen article I stumbled upon [one with the very same name, but by T.E. Gantner](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1971.11992696). It can be read [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/Gantner71.pdf).

Comment: Can you explain why you write $K_0 = ... = \{\xi < \kappa : \pi(q_\xi)\in \pi[V_0]\}$? From what I understand, you're using that $q_\eta\notin V_0$. Why is that?

Comment: @Jakobian: For $\xi\in K_0$ we have $q_\xi\sim\varphi(\xi)\in V_0$, so $\pi(q_\xi)=\pi(\varphi(\xi))\subseteq\pi[V_0]$.

Comment: It's true that $\xi\in K_0$ implies that $\pi(q_\xi)\in \pi[V_0]$, but I'm asking why the opposite implication is true

Comment: @Jakobian: If $\pi(q_\xi)\in\pi[V_0]$, then $q_\xi\sim\langle\eta,w\rangle$ for some $\langle\eta,w\rangle\in V_0$. But $\varphi(\xi)$ is the unique element of $\kappa\times Y$ equivalent to $q_\xi$, so $\varphi(x_\xi)=\langle\eta,w\rangle\in V_0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Wouldn't that only be true if $\langle \eta, w\rangle\in \kappa\times Y$ in the first place? I don't think that's a given.

Comment: @Jakobian: Okay, I think that I’ve finally figured out what the problem is: you’re worried about the possibility that $\pi(q_\eta)\in U$. Yes, that’s an oversight, but it’s easily fixed: the $\sim$-classes in $X$ are closed, so $X'$ is $T_1$, and without loss of generality we can assume that $\pi(q_\eta)\notin U$. I may not get to it until this evening (it’s 15:20 for me now), but I’ll make the necessary small modification at some point today.

Comment: I also have doubts why the second equality after definition of $K_n$ holds. And also the claimed equality $V = \pi^{-1}[U]$. Could you explain those?

Comment: @Jakobian: Until this month I’d not thought about this example in nearly nine years; it would be helpful and save me some time if you could indicate exactly where you see a problem with each of those equations.

Comment: The issue is similar as with $K_0$. We need $\pi(q_\xi)\in \pi[V_n]$ to imply $\varphi(\xi)\in V_n$. For this we need $q_\xi\notin V_n$. This was easy to fix for $n = 0$. For $n > 0$ we'd need something else, I don't know precisely, maybe a proof by induction, or whole modification of the proof, but we need to prevent $q_\xi$ for $\xi\in K_{n-1}$ to belong to $V_n$ somehow. I don't know if this is even salvageable, there is a lot of unproven claims here that follow from nowhere. I don't know if this is important, so maybe we could just delete all of them from $V_n$.

Comment: Since they belong to different $X_\xi$, the set $\{q_\xi : \xi\in K_{n-1}\}$ is still closed, so we could do that without modifying that $V_n$ is open, but I don't know if it doesn't break the proof somewhere along the way.

Comment: I had some help and I found [this article](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v21/tp21014.pdf) by V. Tzannes. They say it's a modification of the argument by van Douwen, so it should help

Comment: @Jakobian: My apologies: I’ve been away for a while dealing with other more urgent things and haven’t had a chance to get back to this. I’ll try to get to it in the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

Edit. My answer below are not precise:
Please read the comment posted by @BrianM.Scott after my answer to see what I really should have said,
as well as to a link to his detailed and self-contained answer to a related question (and for more references).

One such simple example is by Mysior,
A. Mysior, A regular space which is not completely regular
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 81 (1981), 652-653
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601748-4/
It is only a two-page paper with the example described on the first page, and a remark based on it on the second page showing the existence of a regular space such that every real-valued function defined on it is constant. Correction. The example by Mysior is of a regular space in which there are two points $a,b$ with the property that $f(a)=f(b)$ for every continuous real valued function $f$. This example *could be used* to construct a regular space on which every continuous real-valued function is constant. See the comment below by @BrianM.Scott. You may also see Exercises 2.7.17 and 2.7.18 in Engelking, General Topology (1989) (more references there).

Another one is the Tychonoff corkscrew, in Counterexamples in Topology, 
will try to find a link in a minute. This one used to be the standard example, but the example by Mysior is easier to follow.

Can't find the best link, but the Tychonoff corkscrew is based on the [Tychonoff plank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank) (it takes countably many Tychonoff planks and glues them together in a certain way). 
The Tychonoff plank is based on the product $[0,\omega]\times [0,\omega_1]$. These and some related examples (examples 86-91) are described in
[Counterexamples in Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) (1970, 2nd ed. 1978) Lynn Steen and J. Arthur Seebach, Jr.

Comment: None of these is an example of a space on which all real-valued continuous functions are constant: they are examples of $T_3$ spaces with points $p$ and $q$ that cannot be separated by a continuous real-valued function. I describe another, due to Thomas, in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/386811/12042). Any of them can by used to construct the desired example, using the technique in the van Douwen paper cited by Mysior.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Of course you are right, thank you for correcting me, and thank you for providing the link to your answer with the example due to Thomas.

Comment: You’re welcome.