# Continuous real-valued function on a connected space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a homework as follows:

Find connected space $X$ such that all continuous real-valued functions defined on $X$ is constant!

Please help me to find a such space

Comment: What’s the absolutely simplest space that you can think of — a very small space?

Comment: For a less trivial example, you could try proving that an infinite set with the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) has the desired properties; it’s very straightforward.

Comment: singleton set is too trivial example.

Comment: In that case, you should specify that in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an example less trivial than the one-point space, I’ll post my comment as an answer: try showing that an infinite set with the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) has the desired properties.

It’s not Hausdorff; Hausdorff examples are much harder to find. There are even $T_3$ examples, though they’re pretty complicated; if you’re interested, you can learn more about them from the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046079/y-is-t-1-iff-there-is-regular-space-x-s-t-all-continuous-function-from-x).

Answer (score 0):

a single point!

more generally, take any set and take the topology to be the empty set and the whole space

Answer (score 0):

If you consider X={p} just one point! Every function from X to the reals is necessarily 1) continuous, and 2) constant !